# unassign order status from status

Tags: magento

I need to unassign status from state in migration.

```
$status->setStatus('approved')
        ->unassignState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW)
        ->assignState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, false)
        ->save();
```

If status is assigned to migration, it works. But if state is not assigned, there is exception and 
migrations fails. 
What is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that occured to me, is to create function trapper that catches exception. I this case
it seems that migration works even if status is not assigned to state.

```
function unAssignStatusFromState($status, $state)
{
    try {
        $status->unassignState($state);
        return true;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```